# How can i remove update handle in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout

I have removed blocks from xml file using `<referenceBlock name="page.top" remove="true" />` but how can i remove `<update handle="customer_account"/>` from the layout file.

Comment: Please update the answer. I'm stucked & cannot  find it on SO

Answer (score -1):

I think this would be handy to know how to do too, without having to manually revert all the changes that the new layout handle changes.